# What exactly was the Borg's intention when finally capturing the ship at the end of "Q Who"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

If it had not been for Q saving them at the last minute, what would the Borg have done?

Comment: Don't forget the universe tag when asking questions. For this example, use the Star Trek tag (and TNG). I don't know if it can be said for absolute certain what the Borg planned to do. Though since Picard was reduced to begging for Q's help, I think it's likely that the captain thought the Borg planned to outright destroy the *Enterprise*.

Comment: Related but not quite a duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217539/what-exactly-happened-to-the-18-crew-members-who-were-reported-as-missing-in

Answer (score 7):

From what we know of the Borg within the context of "Q Who", their intention was most likely to capture the Enterprise and dismantle it to absorb the ship's technology while killing the crew.

As the Borg and the collective were further developed in subsequent stories, Borg seem to prioritise the assimilation of biological entities as much as technology. So, with this additional dimension, it is likely the crew of the Enterprise would be assimilated along with the ship.

Comment: It's possible that they would have just assimilated the crew and used the data in the Enterprise computers to identify Federation member worlds and species that would be ideally suited to their needs (once assimilated)